# Data not showing in the grid

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

i am currently working with a .net project and what i need to do is to get data from web Service and show them in grid. For some reasons i do not know the grid is not showing the data.
Here is my aspx.cs file

```
    protected void radGridPensionList_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        string ssn = txtSSN.Text.ToString();
        getMypensionListWS pensionList = new getMypensionListWS();

        myPensionerProfitList[] arrayOfPensionList = getPensionProfitList(ssn);

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfPensionList.Length; i++)
        {
            myPensionerProfitList ARRAY = arrayOfPensionList[i];
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //Get details

            list.Add(arrayOfPensionList);
        }
        radGridPensionList.DataSource = list;
    }
   }
```

and the aspx file with the grid code

```
                                 <telerik:RadGrid ID="radGridPensionList" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="radGridPensionList_NeedDataSource" 
                                AllowFilteringByColumn="True" CellSpacing="-1" GridLines="Both" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
                                <clientsettings allowcolumnsreorder="True">
                                    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
                                </clientsettings>
```

<%--                                    AutoGenerateColumns="true"--%>

```
                    <Columns>

                      <%--  <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CUSTOMER_NO" UniqueName="Customer_No" Display="true">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>--%>
                         <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PERSON_ID" HeaderText="PERSON_ID" UniqueName="PERSON_ID" Display="true">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                         <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FIRST_NAME" HeaderText="FIRST_NAME" UniqueName="FIRST_NAME" Display="true">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FATHER_NAME" HeaderText="FATHER_NAME" UniqueName="FATHER_NAME" Display="true">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LAST_NAME" HeaderText="LAST_NAME" UniqueName="LAST_NAME" Display="true">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BIRTH_DATE" HeaderText="BIRTH_DATE" UniqueName="BIRTH_DATE" Display="true">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PFILE_CODE" HeaderText="PFILE_CODE" UniqueName="PFILE_CODE" Display="true">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FILE_TYPE" HeaderText="FILE_TYPE" UniqueName="FILE_TYPE" Display="true">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BIRTH_DAPFILE_DOCUMENT_IDTE" HeaderText="PFILE_DOCUMENT_ID" UniqueName="PFILE_DOCUMENT_ID" Display="true">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PERIOD_ID" HeaderText="PERIOD_ID" UniqueName="PERIOD_ID" Display="true">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PERIOD_NAME" HeaderText="PERIOD_NAME" UniqueName="PERIOD_NAME" Display="true">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PO_CHECK" HeaderText="PO_CHECK" UniqueName="PO_CHECK" Display="true">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="AMOUNT" HeaderText="AMOUNT" UniqueName="AMOUNT" Display="true">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PFILE_POP_ID" HeaderText="PFILE_POP_ID" UniqueName="PFILE_POP_ID" Display="true">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                    </Columns>
                    <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="true" />
                </MasterTableView>

                            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

The code is not giving errors or exceptions. I can see that the grid is taking my list as a datasource but then nothing i showing when i run the app. 
Any idea where i am doing wrong? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: can you call a Databind() method on the grid or a Refresh() method.. have your tried that..? also, why are you creating this inside of your loop `DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //Get details` you only need to do that once outside of the loop.. you need to code review your code as well as use the debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is doing some strange things.

1. Don't use `ArrayList`. Since you can add any object to it, it makes it hard to see that you're adding strange things like you are (see below). Use `List<T>` instead so you can define what can be added to the list.
2. You're declaring 2 variables within your loop (`ARRAY` and `dt`) that you aren't using.
3. You are adding the *same array* to `list` multiple times. I *suspect* you want to just add the *items* to your array and not the array itself:

updated code after correcting these issues:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    var list = new List<myPensionerProfitList>();
    string ssn = txtSSN.Text.ToString();
    getMypensionListWS pensionList = new getMypensionListWS();

    myPensionerProfitList[] arrayOfPensionList = getPensionProfitList(ssn);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfPensionList.Length; i++)
    {
        myPensionerProfitList item = arrayOfPensionList[i];
        list.Add(item);
    }
    radGridPensionList.DataSource = list;
}
```

Which should *work*. If that *does* work you can simplify it by just calling the Linq `ToList` method on the *array* to create a list. Or, since you can bind arrays to data grids just fine, you don't need a list *at all*:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    string ssn = txtSSN.Text.ToString();
    getMypensionListWS pensionList = new getMypensionListWS();

    myPensionerProfitList[] arrayOfPensionList = getPensionProfitList(ssn);

    radGridPensionList.DataSource = arrayOfPensionList;
}
```

Comment: @D Stanley Thank you for the code that worked perfectly and also for the explanation and suggestions